# Where to store .xls file for xlsReadWrite in R

Tags: r, load, xls

I am relatively new to R and am having some trouble with how to access my data. I have my test.xls file created in my MYDocuments. How to I access it from R

```
 library(xlsReadWrite)
 DF1 <- read.xls("test.xls") # read 1st sheet
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is.

Comment: Can you update this question with the error you're getting?

Comment: Why the down votes here?  This is an important problem for beginners to deal with.

Comment: @TylerRinker If the OP had provided the error message they received I wouldn't have down voted. My down vote is not a commentary on how interesting or basic the question is, but how clearly the OP has stated it, that's all.

Comment: @joran this was my first question on stack. I will work harder on being more concise and clear about the specifics of my questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the working directory with:

```
setwd("C:/Documents and Settings/yourname/My Documents")
```

Answer (score 1):

This link may be useful as a method of making working folders per project and then placing all relevant info in that folder.  It's a nice tutorial for making project files that contain everything you need.  This is one approach.

http://www.dangoldstein.com/flash/Rtutorial2/Rtutorial2.html

The setwd() is another approach.  I use a combination of the two in my work.